# hidden element isn't shown by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have those two elements in my html

```
<p id="fullday" hidden="true" >Full Day</p>
 <input type="checkbox"  id="fullday" hidden="true" name="CheckIn">
```

in my js file when i call the function

```
$('#fullday').show();
```

only the `<p>` element is shown and the checkbox is still hidden..
thnx in advance

Comment: Element `id`s must be unique.

Comment: the `hidden` attribute isn't a standard attribute.

Comment: .show() doesn't change the hidden attribute.

Comment: you can also put the <input> inside the <p> and show/hide only the <p> and remove the "id" attribute from the <input>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues here.

1. IDs must be unique

   Instead use classes, which can be used on multiple elements to identify a set of elements.
2. `hidden="none"` is a non standard way of hiding values that you want to show.  From the usage recommendations at MDN

   > This attribute must not be used to hide content that could be legitimately be shown. For example, it shouldn't be used to hide tabs panels of a tabbed interface, as this is a styling decision and another style showing them would lead to a perfectly correct page.

   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#hidden

   Use `display:none` instead, as below, or hide with CSS.

   ```
   <p class="fullday" style="display:none" >Full Day</p>
   <input type="checkbox"  class="fullday" style="display:none" name="CheckIn">
   ```

   Then the js is just

   ```
   $(".fullday").show();
   ```

Comment: isn't the hidden attribute part of the html5 spec?

Comment: show adds an inline style to js.  Specifically the display style.

Comment: @KevinB yes my fault.  Its used in a nonstandard way.  Updating.

Comment: I'm really grateful for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

ID must be UNIQUE!

try to use class instead and $('.fullday') selector.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what W3 schools has to say:

> The id selector is used to specify a style for a single, unique element.
>
> The class selector is used to specify a style for a group of elements. Unlike the id selector, the class selector is most often used on several elements.

Learn the difference between IDs and Classes. Good luck!

Comment: Change your reference to the real W3